# Как поменять местами посты в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Они сортируются по полю порядок/order. Задача в том что бы получить это значение и изменить его, тем самым поменять местами два поста в списке. В голове вертится один способ, но никак не могу его сформулировать и испытать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте плагин [Post Types Order](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/). Он позволяет вручную установить любой порядок постов в админке, простым перетаскиванием.

Comment: Попробую, но вряд ли он мне подойдет. Мне нужно что бы они менялись местами при каждом обновлении страницы. Но может, если покопаться в его коде, что то полезное все таки смогу в нем найти

Comment: Вы делаете суждение, не попробовав применить совет. А плагин как раз так и работает - меняете порядок в админке - и ровно в таком порядке посты выводятся на фронте.

Comment: Это предположение! И я сказал что попробую. Не вижу никакой проблемы в этом